# Python timer is not working as how I wanted it to work

Tags: python, timer

I tried to make a timer that will print stuff when a variable reaches 2502 but instead of doing it at a certain time it just prints is all at once and I can't figure out how to fix it.

```
n1 = str(",..")
n2 = str(".,.")
n3 = str("..,")
print(n1)
timer = 2
while timer < 2502:
    timer += 1
if timer == int("2502"):
    print(n2)
timer2 = 2
while timer2 < 2502:
    timer2 += 1
if timer2 == int("2502"):
    print(n3)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. How long do you think it should take for the variable to reach the target value? Why?

Comment: i timed it and its about 1 second long maybe its a vs code thing

Comment: I doubt that. On my computer, Python can count up to tens of millions of times per second. And it was not an especially good computer, when I bought it 7 years ago.

Comment: Anyway, when i replace the `2502` value with something that makes sense on my system (`19000000` works pretty well for me), I cannot reproduce the problem. That said, if you actually want to time something, you should use an appropriate timing function. Start by putting, for example, `python time delay` into a search engine. That way, you are not dependent on how fast the user's computer is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can insert a time lag in your while loops. (I reduced a bit the time to check the program)

```
import time  # import the module
n1 = str(",..")
n2 = str(".,.")
n3 = str("..,")
print(n1)
timer = 2
while timer < 10: 
    time.sleep(1) # will do nothing for one second
    timer += 1
if timer == int("10"):
    print(n2)
timer2 = 2
while timer2 < 10:
    time.sleep(1) # will do nothing for one second
    timer2 += 1
if timer2 == int("10"):
    print(n3)
```